# How is a # used by the MVC code of the controller and views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

URL : http://www.myserver.com/movies/details/19

Can someone tell me how the number '19' in the URL is used by the MVC code for the controller and views

(I already know how it relates to a particular representation of the domain data)

Comment: This is URL rewriting, either configured by the web server, or directly handled by the application, which parses the request string. Maybe your question needs a little bit more details though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the default route configuration, you'll see that it is built as "/{controller}/{action}/{id}".  If you stick with that and use (int id) as your parameter for the action, that is the value passed into id.

**Edit:** And just in case you need to find that, you can look in the App_Start folder for the RouteConfig.cs file.

Answer (score 0):

What the various pieces of the URL do depend on how your Routes and Controllers are set up.  The asp.net website provides a series of tutorials designed to introduce you to the options:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing